# Backbone.js with Eco Templates: How to include template within a template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, backbone.js, coffeescript

Is it possible to include a template within a template? Maybe something similar to the way ERB handles partials?

Rather than attempting to render nested models in a fashion like ERB, it's better to let Backbone.js take care of this.

Note, I am using coffeescript syntax:

Projects.IndexView

```
template: JST["backbone/templates/projects/index"]

addAll: () ->
    @options.projects.each(@addOne)

addOne: (project) ->
    view = new Worktimer.Views.Projects.ProjectView({model : project})
    @$("#projects-table").append(view.render().el)

render: ->
    $(@el).html(@template(projects: @options.projects.toJSON() ))
    @addAll()
```

the model Project has a nested collection called sessions:

Projects.ProjectView

```
template: JST["backbone/templates/projects/project"]

$(@el).html(@template(@model.toJSON() ))     
for s in @model.sessions.models
    v = new Worktimer.Views.ProjectSessions.ShowView(model: s)
    $(@el).find('.sessions').append(v.render().el)
```

ProjectSessions.ShowView

```
template: JST["backbone/templates/project_sessions/show"]

render: ->
    $(this.el).html(@template(@model.toJSON() ))
```

so, in the end we have nested templates like this:

- Projects Index

  - Project

    - Session
    - Session
    - Session
    - Session
  - Project

    - Session
  - Project

    - Session
    - Session

Answer (score 5):

here a little helper I use for spine:

```
# Render Partials in ECO-Templates like in Rails-ERB
# 
# usefull to clean up structure in spine.js and other js-mvc´s like backbone 
# 
# usage:
#   <%- render_partial 'path/to/partial' %>  ..  will render ../spine-app/views/path/to/_partial.jst.eco
#   <%- render_partial 'path/to/partial', foo: 'bar' %>  ..  will render ../spine-app/views/path/to/_partial.jst.eco  ..  locals = @foo 
#
window.render_partial = ( path, options = {} ) ->
    # add the leading underscore (like rails-partials)
    path = path.split('/')
    path[ path.length - 1 ] = '_' + path[ path.length - 1 ]
    path = path.join('/')
    # render and return the partial if existing
    try
        JST["app/views/#{ path }"]( options )
    catch error
        # if App.Environment != 'production' then "<p class='error'>Sorry, there is no partial named '#{ path }'.</p>" else ''
        "<p class='error'>Sorry, there is no partial named '#{ path }'.</p>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Eco supports this. It's intended more as a simple templating system like Mustache than as a full-fledged ERB replacement. On Rails, you'd probably render an Eco template and inject the output into an ERB or Haml template.

For Node.js development, you might want to take a look at [CoffeeKup](http://coffeekup.org/), which lets you do your templating in CoffeeScript and supports partials.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Eco with Backbone and Rails 3.1. Ended up going with using backbone to inject individual templates within parents.

Answer (score -1):

If you prefix the template with `.erb`, you can use the ERB processor.

Change `yourfile.js.coffee` to `yourfile.js.coffee.erb`, then you'll be able to add `<%= %>` tags to your CoffeeScript template.

Comment: this would be within Eco, so you suggest doing file.jst.eco.erb?

Comment: The more extensions you append, the more processors will be used.

Comment: Also, since ECO and ERB both use `<%= %>`, ERB would gobble up all the interpolations before ECO gets to it! :)