# Partials in Coffee HAML (.hamlc)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript, haml, jst

I am using backbone.js on a rails backend with **[HAML Coffee](https://github.com/netzpirat/haml-coffee)**, which is compiled by [haml_coffee_assets](https://github.com/netzpirat/haml_coffee_assets). There is some duplication in my templates.

Is there a way to create rails-like partials to dry up my templates?

**Addition:** Can I do `content_for(:something)` in Coffee HAML?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no `content_for` helper in Haml Coffee, but you simply can render another template within a template.

### Without Local Variables

For example, you've a template `test`:

```
%p My Partial
%ul
  %li Is included
```

You can include it within another template like this:

```
%p Another template
!= JST['test']()
%p That includes a partial
```

The trick is to unescape the rendered HTML with `!=`.

### With Local Variables

To pass local variables, just send them to the `JST` function. If this is **your partial** (`articles/_comments.jst.hamlc`):

```
%h2=@title
%p=@content
```

Then this may be **your template**:

```
%h1 Comments for this article
- for comment in @article.comments 
  != JST['articles/_comment'](comment)
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you add how to do local variables? Is there a way to emulate `content_for()` or do anything like that? I have a menu bar in my parent template and I want to fill in the buttons from the included partial.

Comment: Found out the local variable thingy myself and edited your post. Still no idea how to do content_for.

Comment: You can define a global context for your Haml Coffee assets, which can also contain a function. So you can mix in something like `{ content_for: (name, context = @) -> JST[name](context) }`, so you can use `@content_for('articles/comment')` It's described the Haml Coffee Readme who to define a global context.

Comment: To add to @Netzpirat's answer I use the `render_partial` helper I found [here on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11131433/376680) and it works great. It is pretty much the same as @Netzpirat's code but with added sugar and support for underscore leading partial file names. Sorry, no `content_for`, thought it might be helpful though :)