# How to embed raw html string attribute into .hamlc template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, client-side-templating, hamlc

Currently I have backbone RIA with rails backend. I'm using haml_coffee_assets gem for client-side templating. But I miss rails view helpers there.

I decided to add raw html strings into my backbone models. 
So, I have this kind of object in my coffeescript

```
Object
  avatar: "/avatars/small/missing.png"
  avatar_link: "<a href="/users/ortepko" class="author" id="user-nick-76"><img src="/avatars/small/missing.png" width="32" /></a>"
  humanized_messages_number: "1 Message "
  id: 76
  login_name_link: "<a href="/users/ortepko" class="author" id="user-nick-76">ortepko</a>"
```

my template code becomes pretty simple

```
.text_content
  .comment
    = @contact.avatar_link
    .text
      = @contact.login_name_link
      .messages
        %a{href: '#'}
          = @contact.humanized_messages_number
```

Now I want to render a template

```
JST['messages/yet_another_template'] {contact: contact}
```

But it does not seem to be working.

Comment: Just found an answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201593/partials-in-coffee-haml-hamlc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found an answer here:
[Partials in Coffee HAML (.hamlc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9201593/partials-in-coffee-haml-hamlc)

My Template should look like

```
.text_content
  .comment
    != @contact.avatar_link
    .text
      != @contact.login_name_link
      .messages
        %a{href: '#'}
          = @contact.humanized_messages_number
```

Thanks to Netzpirat!

Comment: Is it safe? Like XSS issues?

Comment: @DmitryPolushkin , XSS safety is up to you. In my case I've rendered HTML to json object on the server side and have a full control on it's safety